# How to make legent in pie amchart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, amcharts

Demo and my code is like this : https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/4qdan7k7/6/

I using :

```
"legend": {
   "useGraphSettings": true
}
```

But it's not working. The result like this :  [image]

Any solution to solve my problem?

Comment: Please provide the description of what is expected as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `useGraphSettings`, because you have no `graphs` in your settings:

```
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataProvider": chartData,
  "valueField": "litres",
  "titleField": "country",
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "legend": {},
});
```

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/uqoo0qbs/)